# How to add multiple latitude and longitude in location tracking google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here i am doing location tracking , in this google API two location(lat,lng) only providing. but i need to add one more location(lat,lng).how can i do this? i spent more time but i am not able find solution.Here two lacations are there so map marker showing like A and B, suppose i will add one more it it should show A and B and C.[image: please see my screenshot]

```js
function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937},  // Haight.
          destination: {lat: 12.9630167, lng: 77.6268656},  // Domlur.
          // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
          // using square brackets and a string value as its
          // "property."
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
      <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
      <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
      <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are [**waypoints**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints).

> A waypoint consists of the following fields:
>
> **location (required)** specifies the address of the waypoint.
>
> **stopover (optional)** indicates whether this waypoint is a actual stop on the route (true) or instead only a preference to route through
> the indicated location (false). Stopovers are true by default.

You can pass an array of [**waypoints**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) to DirectionsService's `route()` method. A [**waypoint**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) could look like this:

```
var waypoint = {
    location: {lat: 12.9590167, lng: 77.7064937},
    stopover: true
}

// or

var waypoint = {
    location: 'Some address, city',
    stopover: true
}
```

And you can also see the google's example [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)

```js
function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        
        /* configure waypoints */
        var waypts = [];
        waypts.push({
              location: {lat: 12.9590167, lng: 77.7064937},
              stopover: true
            },{
              location: {lat: 12.9600167, lng: 77.7364937},
              stopover: true
            });
            
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: 12.9577129, lng: 77.6764937},  // Haight.
          destination: {lat: 12.9630167, lng: 77.6268656},  // Domlur.
          // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
          // using square brackets and a string value as its
          // "property."
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
          waypoints: waypts
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
      <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
      <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
      <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Here waypts array we have two values(lat,lng) and destination we have one  value(lat,lng).why we are doing like this,

Comment: @subikshanM there are some links to the documentation, please go and read there. When you call `route()` method you are required to always pass `origin` and `destination`. If you want to pass any points between those two you can optionally do it with `waypoints`. That's it and this is the design of google library. You can put in `waypoints` as many as you wish

Comment: In my database i have 10 values(lat,lng).from this values how do like what we did now

Comment: @subikshanM get your values from the database somehow, it's up to you, and then simply insert them in array with objects of [**waypoint**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) structure. Then simply pass this array to `route({waypoints: yourWaypointsArray})`. Also go and read the code above and try to understand it

Comment: @subikshanM sounds great. Good job!

Comment: Mr@ codtex, i have one small question please, suppose if i clicked that marker marker it is showing address, insteed of address i want show some static value how can do this?

Comment: @subikshanM check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484132/5452965) and also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457013/5452965) to see how markers with custom info windows are created, try to understand the code. Basically you need to re-create those markers if you want to change the default message and this is done in `route()` method's callback. See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29362018/5452965) example for details